# Is there a variable type "cell" in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to keep `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` as a variable?
I haven't found a type "cell".
Something like

```
Dim mycell As cell
mycell = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1
```

doesn't work.

Comment: use a string variable to save the formula

Comment: The correct type of object for a cell is `Range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a string variable to store the formula and assign it to another cell's property.

```
Dim mycellFormula As string
mycellFormula = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1
cells(1,1) = mycellFormula
```